# Who was the first to notice that the bias can be decomposed into model bias and estimation bias?

Tags: references, bias-variance-tradeoff, history

As the title says, who was the first to notice that the bias can be decomposed into model bias and estimation bias?

For reference, I'm talking about the quantities here at page 224 eq. (7.14)
https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/ESLII.pdf

[image]

It seems unlikely that Hastie et al were the first to observe this, given the long history of OLS and ridge regression.  So the question is - what is the original reference for this? Who noticed this first?

Comment: Note that this decomposition holds for *linear models* but not necessarily in general.